# How to extract lines from txt file in Linux

Tags: grep

I have text file with 25 millions of lines (a list of domain names).

How can I extract domains that contain `.co.uk` to another txt file?

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a sample of the file?

Comment: if you could provide a sample it would be better, but anyway maybe just simple `grep ".co.uk" file > file2` can do the job.

Comment: @binarysta, you have to either add `-F` or escape the dots, see the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -F '.co.uk' file > filtered_file
```

`-F` lets `grep` search for a fixed string instead of a pattern which makes it a lot faster, especially given your 25 million lines. Then, you also don't need to escape the dots, which are special characters for a pattern.

Note, that this will also find lines like `example.co.uk.com` or `example.co.uk/index.html`. If you want the `.co.uk` always in the end, go with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582166/236063) answer.

Answer (score 4):

Given a file like:

```
foo.co.uk
bar.co.uk
baz.foo.bar
```

use the command:

```
grep "\.co\.uk$" file
```

Output:

```
foo.co.uk
bar.co.uk
```